# Crash when trying to measure a ComposeView to generate a bitmap of it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to generate a bitmap through a ComposeView, but this exception is being thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot locate windowRecomposer; View androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView{620841 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} is not attached to a window
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WindowRecomposer_androidKt.getWindowRecomposer(WindowRecomposer.android.kt:225)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.resolveParentCompositionContext(ComposeView.android.kt:244)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.ensureCompositionCreated(ComposeView.android.kt:251)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onMeasure(ComposeView.android.kt:288)
> at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20238)

This is how I'm generating the bitmap:

```
val view = ComposeView(context).apply {
    this.setContent {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(text = "Hello Stack Overflow")
        }
    }
    this.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0
    )
    this.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
    // !!! exception being thrown here, on measure !!!
    this.measure(
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(384, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    )
    this.layout(0, 0, this.measuredWidth, this.measuredHeight)
}

val bitmap = Bitmap
    .createBitmap(view.measuredWidth, view.measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

view.draw(canvas)
```

Am I forgetting to do something?

Comment: What is it that you actually want to achieve? If it's getting an Android Bitmap with text via a Compose canvas, I think there are canvas text drawing primitives in the latest compose alphas. This might be preferable over going through a full-fledged Android View.

Comment: did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Did you fix it? Same problem here...